# SSH ProxyCommand on AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, ssh, git, amazon-web-services

Trying to use ssh with ProxyCommand on AWS Lambda but it falls over. Im not sure why. Im basically doing a git clone, which was working but now the git server is beyond a jump host. I've got git clone working on others machines, but on lambda I'm getting (the keys and ssh config file are written into the /tmp folder (also using https://github.com/pimterry/lambda-git for git/ssh):

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /tmp/ssh_config
debug1: /tmp/ssh_config line 16: Applying options for bitbucker_server
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /tmp/git/usr/bin/ssh -vvv -F /tmp/ssh_config inter -W bitbucket_server:7999
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 482
setresuid 482: Operation not permitted
debug1: identity file /tmp/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /tmp/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Im wondering if it has anything to do with the permanently_drop_suid as the setup works outside of lambda.

The same operation outside of lambda...

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 
debug1: Reading configuration data /tmp/ssh_config
debug1: /tmp/ssh_config line 15: Applying options for bitbucket_server
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -vvv inter -W bitbucket_server:7999
debug1: identity file /tmp/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /tmp/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user_name/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user_name/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for inter
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -A jump -W bibucket_server:22
debug1: identity file /home/user_naem/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user_name/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
.
.
.
```

Anybody???